# How to set a combined maxlength of three input fielsd in angular 9+ dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm wanting to set a combined maximum length of 1400 for three input fields in angular, so if say that for the first field the user enters 400 characters, in the second and third fields the maxlength becomes 1000.

I have found one answer at StackOverflow but that is for angularjs and not working even if I follow so please give me angular 9 solution trying to solve this issue for 4days now

progress so far...

TS file

```
getMaxLength(val): void{
    this.remaining = this.MAX_LENGTH - (
    this.summary.nativeElement.value.length + 
    this.insights.nativeElement.value.length + 
    this.recommendations.nativeElement.value.length
    );
    this.summaryLimit = this.MAX_LENGTH - (this.summary.nativeElement.value.length)
    this.insightLimit = this.MAX_LENGTH - (this.insights.nativeElement.value.length)
    this.recommLimit = this.MAX_LENGTH - (this.recommendations.nativeElement.value.length) 
  }
```

html file

```
<form [formGroup]="wrapReportForm" class="wrap_form">

        <div class="wrap_input">

          <span>{{remaining}}</span>

          <label class="label-required" for="summary"

            >Summary </label

          >

          <textarea

            formControlName="summary"

            #summary

            type="text"

            maxlength="{{summaryLimit}}"

            (ngChange)="getMaxLength($event)"

            name="summary"

            placeholder="Enter some input"

            wrap="soft"

          ></textarea>

          <!-- (keydown)="getMaxLength($event, summary.value?.lead)" -->

          <!-- <span>{{ summary.value?.length || 0 }}/{{maxLength1}}</span> -->

        </div>

        <div class="wrap_input">

          <label class="label-required">Insights </label>

          <textarea

            formControlName="insights"

            type="text"

            name="insights"

            #insights

            maxlength="{{insightLimit}}"

            (ngModelChange)="getMaxLength($event)"

            placeholder="Enter some input"

          ></textarea>

          <!-- <span>{{ insights.value?.length || 0 }}/{{maxLength2}}</span> -->

        </div> 
<div class="wrap_input">

          <label class="label-required">Recommendations </label>

          <textarea

            formControlName="recommendations"

            type="text"

            name="recommendations"

            #recommendations

            maxlength="{{recommLimit}}"

            (ngModelChange)="getMaxLength($event)"

            placeholder="Enter some input"

          ></textarea>

          <!-- (keydown)="getMaxLength($event, recommendations.value?.length)" -->

          <!-- <span>{{ recommendations.value?.length || 0 }}/{{maxLength3}}</span> -->

        </div>

        <div class="wrapReport_buttons">

          <button class="margin-right-sm outline" mat-dialog-close >Cancel</button>

          <button class="fill" (click)="generateWrapReport(true)" mat-dialog-close>Send Request</button>

        </div>

      </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom validator to check the maxlength of the 3 controls and set it on the form.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, thanks you answered but could you share the code because I was getting an edge case where if I paste let's say 400 char each time in summary input field later I won't be able to paste it even the limit has been 600, it's because 400*3 pastbecome 1200 input length and limit becomes 600

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
getMaxLength(val): void{ 

this.remaining = this.MAX_LENGTH - ( this.summary.nativeElement.value.length + this.insights.nativeElement.value.length + this.recommendations.nativeElement.value.length ); 

this.summaryLimit = this.MAX_LENGTH - (this.insights.nativeElement.value.length+this.recommendations.nativeElement.value.length ) 

this.insightLimit = this.MAX_LENGTH - (this.summary.nativeElement.value.length + this.recommendations.nativeElement.value.length) 

this.recommLimit = this.MAX_LENGTH - (this.summary.nativeElement.value.length + this.insights.nativeElement.value.length) 
}
```